# PHP Write to different files using IP Address

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to write POST data to a file using an IP address as a `UUID`

Example: 123.45.67.89 Submits the form file becomes 123-45-67-89.txt and the contents are then placed inside the file

current code I have is below

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$filename = str_replace(".", "-", $ip);
$formdata = $_POST["Question"] " - " $_POST["Answer"];
file_put_contents($filename, $formdata, 'w');`
```

basically taking the question & answer and writing it to a file

Comment: And?  What is your specific question?

Comment: What is the result of your code? Which part is not working?

Comment: bad idea, it might be 1000 users connected behind a proxy....

Comment: @gview I'm wondering why the code is not creating a file and writing the data to it

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @JanZahradník File doesnt create and doesnt log to it

Comment: `Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30085008/4833713) fixed it, I was using file_put_contents thinking it could take 3 parameters instead of 2

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're using this to get a unique file one a per visitor basis, it will not work. i.p addresses are not unique to anything.

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair It's not for per `visitor` per say, it's more like a per household type of thing

Comment: @RoXes even then, this isn't really going to work...for example, at my workplace I share a single i.p with about ~120 people, but at home, every device in the house has a different address, and then that changes every time you connect to the router...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will fail for two reasons: Your concatenation is wrong in `$formdata`.
And, `file_put_contents` takes 2 parametes, you might be confused with `fopen`.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$filename = str_replace(".", "-", $ip) . ".txt";
$formdata = $_POST["Question"] . " - " . $_POST["Answer"];
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($fp, $formdata);
fclose($fp);
```

Documentation for `file_put_contents` can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), and `fopen` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm still rather new to PHP and your answer helps a lot. I need to go re read file_put_contents I've accepted your answer as it was the most helpful, Thank you.